# How to construct a conditional COUNTIF formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet where in D I have time **(0600,1800,2400)** and in R I have disposition e.g **(accomplished, pending etc)**.

What I want is a formula to count the disposition in column R as per the time period in column D.

I've tried COUNTIF:

```
=IF(C4:C111,">="&TIME(18,0,0),C4:C111,"<="&TIME(23,59,0)*COUNTIF(R2:R109,"pending"))
```

Comment: Hi Sal, it looks like you need the `COUNTIFS()` function

Comment: Are the times ordinary times like `12:51` or are they already categorized `0600`, `1800`, or `2400`?

Comment: it is ordinary times

Answer (score 1):

Sal,

I have a different method that I sometimes use when countif isn't working properly. In Excel, you can use an if statement to return an array of values as well as individual ones which people are not always aware of.

Here is the statement I used to count everything that is "accomplished":

```
{=SUM(IF(R:R="accomplished",D:D,0))}
```

Notice the curly brackets surrounding the statement. When typing the formula, once done hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of just Enter to submit the formula and then Excel will treat this like an array.

Basically the If statement will return the corresponding D column value if its R column value = "accomplished" and then just sum them up.

Of course, you can change the static value to reference another cell too which I am sure you can figure out.

You can also embed another IF statement within the original IF as well.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=COUNTIFS(D1:D100,"06:00",R1:R100,"accomplished")

=COUNTIFS(D1:D100,"06:00",R1:R100,"pending")

=COUNTIFS(D1:D100,"18:00",R1:R100,"accomplished")

=COUNTIFS(D1:D100,"18:00",R1:R100,"pending")

=COUNTIFS(D1:D100,"23:59",R1:R100,"accomplished")

=COUNTIFS(D1:D100,"23:59",R1:R100,"pending")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, you might try something like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(C4:C111,">="&TIME(18,0,0),C4:C111,"<="&TIME(23,59,0),R2:R109,"Pending")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be create a Pivot table to cover those two columns, and change the values from sum to count

Implemented:

[image]

Comment: This is the right idea, but the implementation will be a little more involved though since the time data hasn't been categorized yet. See the comments above.